# Cant share Auth::check() in App\Http\Controllers\Controller via view()->share

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to share in every view **Auth::check() result** as a **$signedIn** variable, i found that i can do it via Parent Controller in Laravel. It works good, but it doesn't want to work for **Auth::check()** - it returns nothing.

**Code for a parent Controller**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

        public function __construct()
        {
            view()->share('signedIn', Auth::check());
        }
    }
```

**Code of the view, in which i use $signedIn variable mentioned before**

```
@if($signedIn)

    @include('question.answer-form')

@else

    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <p>
            <a href="{{ url('login') }}">Sign in</a> in order to answer a question
        </p>
    </div>

@endif
```

In the constructor of the  controller, from which i redirect to the view, i've called a parent constructor - the problem is that it doesn't want to work for **Auth::check()**.

Laravel 5.3v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

try that :

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
          view()->share('signedIn', Auth::check());

          return $next($request);
     });
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

Answer (score 2):

You should place calls to share within a **service** provider's **boot** method

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('signedIn', Auth::check());
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I agree with @Alexey that this doesn't seem like something useful to be shared (maybe sharing the auth()->user() would be), this seems to be the best way to share a variable with all views of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `Auth::check()` result to the views doesn't make any sense since `Auth` is available in all views by default, so does `auth()` global helper. So just use one of these checks in any Blade view. They all do the same:

```
@if (Auth::check())
@if (auth()->check())
@if (Auth::user())
@if (auth()->user())
```

Comment: I know about this checks, just wanted to add this variables in order to make code a bit cleaner

Comment: In my opinion, `auth()->check()` is more readable than some variable. You always know what exactly this code does. Keep it simple. )